# Error in ConfusionMatrix: "data" and "reference" should be factors with the same levels

Tags: r

I am trying to do a kfold cross validation with logistics regression but ran into some errors when trying to run the confusion matrix. I cannot figure out how to solve this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

In addition:

Warning message:

> In predict.lm(object, newdata, se.fit, scale = 1, type = if (type ==  :prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading

Here is my code:

```
for(i in 1:10){
  fold_val <- tele.df[folds[[i]],] 
  fold_train <- tele.df[-folds[[i]],] 
  tele.default.lr <- glm(Churn ~ ., data = fold_train, family = "binomial")
  tele.default.lr.pred.train <- predict(tele.default.lr, fold_train, type = "response")
  print(confusionMatrix(tele.default.lr.pred.train, as.factor(fold_train$Churn)))
  
  tele.default.lr.pred.valid <- predict(tele.default.lr, fold_val, type = "response")
  print(confusionMatrix(tele.default.lr.pred.valid, as.factor(fold_val$Churn)))
```

Comment: you have some redundant predictors, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242540/r-lm-could-anyone-give-me-an-example-of-the-misleading-case-on-prediction-fr

Comment: for the confusion matrix, you can do `cm = table(tele.default.lr.pred.train,fold_train$Churn) ; confusionMatrix(cm)`

Comment: Why do you use just the `confusionMatrix` function from [caret](https://topepo.github.io/caret/) package and not `trainControl` and  `train` to make the k-fold corss-validation??